# Pausing app downloads on Apple TV 4

Tags: appletv

Can you pause app downloads on the new Apple TV?

I can't find any way to do that except deleting the entire download.

Comment: Download of what in particular? There are many things - portions of apps, photos, purchases, movies, app initial install bundles, channel initial downloads...

Comment: sorry, I meant apps

Comment: Got it -my guess is there will never be a pause for that, but let's see if someone found it in case Apple implemented that action.

Comment: That would be weird. On iOS you can pause a download just by tapping it (which currently does nothing on the TV, so... would be logic)